# Metric for calculating lopsided distributions

Tags: statistics

I have a list of ~20 numbers:

> 1200, 1200, 360, 360, 300, 250, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 90, 90, 90, 90, 45, 10, 0, 0

I am looking for a metric that determines the *lopsidedness* (maybe skewness) of this distribution. For the above example, I would want to be able to highlight that the sum of the first 2 numbers (2400) make up nearly 50% of the total sum (4985). But there could also be other examples where the top 4 or 5 numbers make up a big percentage (say, greater than 50%) of the total sum.

Should I just calculate *skewness* or are there other better metrics that fulfill my requirement?

Comment: Look at [_Pearson's Coefficient of Skewness_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) for a start. // If it weren't for the zeros, you might get something more useful looking at logged data.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what precisely you want your 'lopsidedness measure' to reveal. However, I found your question interesting, and so I invented a 'lopsidedness measure', $\mathcal{L}$, that you might find useful (Before I continue, I want to make clear that even though I said I invented this, almost certainly I'm not the first to think of this. I just haven't personally heard of it before.)

---

*How to calculate $\mathcal L$:*

First, make sure that your array of numbers is sorted in an decreasing order (As yours are):

> 1200, 1200, 360, 360, 300, 250, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 90, 90, 90, 90, 45, 10, 0, 0

Next, calculate the cumulative sum of these numbers

> 1200, 2400, 2760, 3120, 3420, 3670, 3850, 4030, 4210, 4390, 4570, 4660, 4750, 4840, 4930, 4975, 4985, 4985, 4985

Now divide by the total sum of your original vector (which happens to be the last element of the cumulative sum, namely 4985):

> 0.241, 0.481, 0.554, 0.626, 0.686, 0.736, 0.772, 0.808, 0.845, 0.881, 0.917, 0.935, 0.953, 0.971, 0.989, 0.998, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000

Now take the average of these numbers. The result is
$$\mathcal L = 0.810$$

---

*Properties of $\mathcal L$:*

The measure $\mathcal L$ is a real number in the interval $(0.5, 1]$, i.e. $0.5<\mathcal L \leq 1$.

When the data is at its most lopsidedness, that is when all the weight is gathered in a single entry in the sequence of numbers, then $\mathcal L = 1$.

On the other hand, the less and less lopsidedness the sequence of numbers are, i.e. the closer the weight is to being uniformly distributed, the closer the measure comes close to a half. The way to see this is the following. Create a vector of some length $n$, with all numbers equal, then you will find that $\mathcal L \approx 0.5$. If you continuously increase the numbers of elements in your sequence, if you let $n\to \infty$, then you will have that $\mathcal L \to 0.5$ from above.

---

*Examples:*

In your example, you see that your numbers are moderately 'lopsided' with $\mathcal L = 0.810$ being a bit higher than midway between $0.5$ and $1$.

Now try with a more lopsided sequence of numbers:

> 1000, 800, 700, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1

from which we calculate $\mathcal L = 0.946$.

Lastly, we try with a sequence of numbers that is very non-lopsided (i.e. weight close to evenly distributed):

> 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 89, 88, 86, 83, 78

from which we calculate $\mathcal L = 0.555$.

Comment: Wow that's great stuff. Thanks! I was planning to do an analysis on tennis ranking data. More precisely, I want to identify players that have very lopsided rankings, that is, their ranking points depend on a few very good results. I will apply your measure in my analysis and refer to this answer in my post and report back here. Thanks again.

Comment: @beta Hope it helps! I found your question interesting, so I gave it some thought. While I was 'inventing' the measure I also had other ideas in mind, so if you ever get even more precise with what you need to measure, I may have some ideas on how to improve the technique. By the way, if you wish to normalize the measure between $0$ and $1$, then simply do the calculation 
$$\mathcal L_{\text{normalized}} = 2\times(\mathcal L -0.5) $$